# Smallest class of linear algebraic groups that is closed under intersections and contains all reductive groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider a class $C$ of linear algebraic groups over $k$ such that

- every reductive group is in $C$.
- If $H_1 \hookrightarrow G$, $H_2 \hookrightarrow G$ such that $H_i, G \in C$, then $H_1 \cap H_2 \in C$.

Can we describe the smallest class satisfying the property? Do any/every solvable group lie in it ?

Motivation: the intersection of two reductive subgroups inside a reductive group may not be reductive.

Answer (score 2):

There are solvable groups inside your class C.  Let $G=SL_3$ and $H=SL_2$ passing through the highest root and its negative root (the one which fixes the second basis vector $e_2$, and leaves stable the span of $e_1,e_3$). The intersection of all the conjugates of $H$ under the Borel subgroup of upper triangular matrices in $G$ (being a finite intersection since $G$ is Noetherean) lies in the class C. But is is easy to see that this intersection is just the group of unipotent upper triangular matrices in the subgroup $H$ and is therefore not reductive.

Comment: Thank you! I know similar example before, like $H_1=GL_2$ in $G=GL_3$ $H_2=gH_1g^{-1}$ with $g=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 &1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. I shall mean that whether every solvable group lie in the class... Btw, one can prove that although $H_1 \cap H_2$ may not be reductive, $H_1 \cap gH_2g^{-1}$ is indeed reductive for some $g$.

Comment: well, one of your questions was whether solvable groups lie in your class.

Comment: I am a little careless.. thank you anyway.